# Does Azure MySQL 8 service with region HA support XA transactions?

Tags: mysql, replication, azure, distributed-transactions

I need to configure a MySQL cluster in Azure with region HA that supports XA transactions.

MySQL does not support XA transactions when replication is in place for our current setup with Percona XTradb (managed by us), so we are exploring some options with Azure's managed services.

From what I gather, with a MySQL flexible server, zonal HA can be configured, which essentially recoveres data at the storage level, so no replication, so XA should work, but we need region-level failover capabilities.

Is there a way to configure a Azure MySQL service with region HA/failover that supports XA transactions?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is possible.

From Microsoft support:

*"XA is supported as this is depends on the storage engine (Innodb which supports the XA) , and the client driver/connector to understand the XA SQL statements and the customer application through the transaction manager should manage these things , and also recently we added to Azure database for MySQL version 8 a new role which is “XA_RECOVER_ADMIN” to help the customers to recover the XA transactions in case of any failures as the behavior changed a little bit on MySQL version 8 compared with previous versions"*

Also, they did not say, but this property has to be like this:

`binlog_format=ROW`